# JS - How get value from resolved promes via Promise.All

Tags: javascript

i need to get value from promise, set it value to field of object and return object.

`array.election[0].candidates` - is array of objects.

```
   async getCandidates(array) {
        return await array.election[0].candidates.map(candidate => {
            let candidateInfo = candidate;
            let balance = 0;
            Promise.all([this.getBalance(candidate.address)]).then(value => {
               balance = value[0];
            });
            candidateInfo.balance = balance;
            return candidateInfo;
        });
    }
```

Because Promise.all - async i cant get value.

Comment: Do `let info = await Promise.all([this.getBalance(candidate.address)]); let balance = value[0];`.  Or better yet, why even use `Promise.all()`?  Just do `let info = await this.getBalance(candidate.address);`

Comment: Why are you even calling `Promise.all` on an array with a single promise only?

Comment: So, i make:


    `async getCandidates(array) {
        let x = array.election[0].candidates.map(async candidate => {
            let candidateInfo = candidate;
            candidateInfo.balance = await this.getBalance(candidate.address);
            return candidateInfo;
        });
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    }`


Without promise.all , but it's make array with promises: http://joxi.ru/Vrw9xlPiOgGMV2
But i need resolved it, can you help me pls?